# If I want to track virtual PageView for Modal, should I send another current page's PageView when user turn of the Modal?

Tags: google-analytics

I want to send custom(Virtual) PageView when Modal shows.

**But when users turn off the Modal**, should I send the current page's PageView in order to let GA determine how long I stay to that Virtual PageView?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a valid best practice for the reason you said and also because if you send an event it will be associated to the last page sent to Analytics, so if you don't send it and the event is on the main page, it will be associated with the virtual page of the modal instead of where it actually clicked.